# iOS - Get first name and last name using Google SignIn SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I am using the Google Sign In SDK and it works perfectly. I am able to get the following data:

```
NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
NSString *name = user.profile.name;
NSString *email = user.profile.email;
```

How could I retrieve the first name and the last name? And other information, for instance City the user lives in, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced similar problem like yours. You cannot get first name and last name separately from Google SDK. Instead you can do it manually as follows,

```
NSString *name = user.profile.name;
NSArray *items = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];   //take one array for splitting the string
NSString *fname = [items objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lname = [items objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score -2):

You already have the first and last name in `user.profile.name` which is the full name.

For other information, you can call the web API:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?fields=aboutMe%2Cbirthday%2CcurrentLocation%2CplacesLived&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

you can get other infor by putting more parameters. For more details, Google explains it here

```
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#examples
```

Comment: I want to achieve this using the Google iOS SDK. Plus, I want the first name and last name separately...Full name doesn't help.